# Angular 6 ES6 initiate object arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class, es6-class

I'm really new to javascript.

I have a nested class structure where I need to initiate using a json object. My question is how can I initiate array of EventDate objects and assign to this.dates in CustomerEvents constructor

```
   export default class CustomerEvent {
        constructor(customer_event: any) {
            this.event_title = customer_event.event_title;
            this.customer = customer_event.customer;
            this.total_budget = customer_event.total_budget;
            this.no_of_people = customer_event.no_of_people;
            this.dates = /**array of new EventDate(customer_event.dates) **/;
        }
        event_title: string;
        customer: Customer;
        total_budget: number;
        no_of_people: number;
        dates: EventDate[];

    }

    class EventDate {
        constructor(date: any) {
            this.start_date = date.start_date;
            this.end_date = date.end_date;
        }
        start_date: Date;
        end_date: Date;
    }
```

If someone could help me on this, it'll be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign new empty array, like this:

```
constructor(customer_event: any) {
  this.event_title = customer_event.event_title;
  this.customer = customer_event.customer;
  this.total_budget = customer_event.total_budget;
  this.no_of_people = customer_event.no_of_people;
  this.dates = [];
}
```

If you need to cast incoming array, you can do this:

```
...
this.dates = customer_event.dates.map(date => new EventDate(date));
...
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Angular Style Guide recommends**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03) using `interface`s for data model instead of `class`es:

> Consider using an interface for data models.

That being said, you can refactor your code like this:

```
export interface EventDate {
  start_date: Date;
  end_date: Date;
}

export interface CustomerEvent {
  event_title: string;
  customer: Customer;
  total_budget: number;
  no_of_people: number;
  dates: EventDate[];
}
```

Now when it comes to initialization, you can do it something like this:

```
const customerEvent: CustomerEvent = {
  event_title: 'Some Title',
  customer: { /*An Object representing a Customer Type*/ }
  total_budget: 123,
  no_of_people: 456,
  dates: [{
    start_date: new Date(),
    end_date: new Date()
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Create those instances yourself:

```
constructor(customer_event: any) {
    this.event_title = customer_event.event_title;
    this.customer = customer_event.customer;
    this.total_budget = customer_event.total_budget;
    this.no_of_people = customer_event.no_of_people;
    this.dates = customer_event.dates.map(date => new EventDate(date));
}
```